# TemplateMatcher with type constraint?

Tags: routes, .net-6.0

I'm using `TemplateMatcher` in .NET 6 (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`) to manually match a string to a route-template such as "`{name}/{id:int?}`", but I cannot get it to respect the type-constraint on the last parameter. It seem to recognize that it has a constraint and that it is an optional parameter, but the value in the resulting value-dictionary is still just string. It also matches strings that is not on the correct format, ie for instance "`a/b`". I just want it to match "`a/1`" etc. Any clue why? Something I have missed? Is there a better class for this purpose somewhere else in .NET? I'd like something that behaves the same way as standard asp.net routes work.

Comment: What is the specific route template you are trying to match and expected results? If its `{name}/{id:int?}` , then the optional ? goes after the name not type `{name}/{id?:int}`.

Comment: That wasn't it, the ? always have to come last apparently. TryMatch throws an exception otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

See [IntRouteConstraintsTests](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v8.0.0/src/Http/Routing/test/UnitTests/Constraints/IntRouteConstraintsTests.cs#L22) in ASP.NET Core codebase.

Implemented by the following code.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Template;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var routeTemplates = new[]
{
    "/{blogApp}/{postType}/{id:int}/{**slug}",
    "/{blogApp}/{postType}/{idOrSlug}.html"
};

var url = "https://www.cnblogs.com/cmt/p/17520031.html";
var urlPath = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath;

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOptions<RouteOptions>();
using ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var routeOptions = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RouteOptions>>();
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver(routeOptions, sp);

foreach (string routeTemplate in routeTemplates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("routeTemplate: " + routeTemplate);
    var parsedTemplate = TemplateParser.Parse(routeTemplate);

    var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
    var matcher = new TemplateMatcher(parsedTemplate, values);
    if (matcher.TryMatch(urlPath, values))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TemplateMatcher matched: true");
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        foreach (var parameter in parsedTemplate.Parameters)
        {
            foreach (var inlineConstraint in parameter.InlineConstraints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(parameter.Name + ":" + inlineConstraint.Constraint);

                var routeConstraint = constraintResolver.ResolveConstraint(inlineConstraint.Constraint);
                var routeDirection = RouteDirection.IncomingRequest;
                bool matched = routeConstraint!.Match(httpContext: null, route: null, parameter.Name!, values, routeDirection);

                Console.WriteLine($"{routeConstraint.GetType().Name} matched: {matched}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
routeTemplate: /{blogApp}/{postType}/{id:int}/{**slug}
TemplateMatcher matched: true
blogApp: cmt
postType: p
id: 17520031.html
slug:
id:int
IntRouteConstraint matched: False

routeTemplate: /{blogApp}/{postType}/{idOrSlug}.html
TemplateMatcher matched: true
blogApp: cmt
postType: p
idOrSlug: 17520031
```

Comment: [ConstraintsTestHelper.cs#L8](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/test/UnitTests/Constraints/ConstraintsTestHelper.cs#L8)

Comment: dudu, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Added code to the solution.